# How to Sort Generic.List(of T) with a custom Class?

Tags: vb.net

I have a class,

```
Public Class PairComboBoxItem
    Private _value As String
    Private _text As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal value As String, ByVal text As String)
        _value = value
        _text = text
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return _text
    End Function

    Public Function value() As String
        Return _value
    End Function
End Class
```

And I have use this to create a List using `Generic.List`

`Dim newListofCmbPrItems As New Generic.List(Of PairComboBoxItem)`

What I want to do is sort the List by the `_text` property of the `PairComboBoxItem` class.

I read something about the `IComparable` interface, but don't know how to use it.

Thank you and Regards,

Comment: Read all three parts of [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/06/sorting-arrays-and-collections-part-1.html).  If you want to use the `IComparable(Of T)` interface then you need to implement it in the item class itself.  The `IComparer(Of T)` interface is implemented in a separate class and the `Comparison(Of T)` delegate can be used on an ad hoc basis.

Comment: By the way, your class is poorly implemented.  Get rid of the `value` function, change the private fields to public properties, e.g. `Private _value As String` becomes `Public Property Value As String`, and have `ToString` return the `Text` property.  If you then implement `IComparable(Of PairComboBoxItem)`, you can compare the `Text` property values.

Comment: You don't have a `_text` Property. You have a Field, which is also `private`. But you can use the value returned by the `ToString()` method (or use public properties instead of fields). Something like: `Dim sorted = newListofCmbPrItems.OrderBy(Function(item) item.ToString()).ToList()`. If you don't want the standard string order, you have to specify what kind of order IComparable should generate.

Comment: Also, the class name should just be `ComboBoxItem` or maybe even `ListControlItem`, given that you would use the same class in a `ListBox`.

Comment: @Jimi, I would not recommend using LINQ in this case because it means creating a new `List` object.  Given that the existing `List` has its own `Sort` method, that would be the more desirable option in this case.  If the items were being created from some other data as the sorting was done, then I'd go with LINQ.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sir, Can you lead me on how to implement the link you have suggested?

Comment: @Jimi, I know Sir, But ther is a Function `ToString()` Where the _text is return

Comment: @jmcilhinney , It's Okay now Sir, I have successfully implemented it. Thank you!

Comment: @jmcilhinney , If you transfer it as an answer Sir, I will accept if as the solution. Again, Thank you :D

Comment: @jmcilhinney I agree. I didn't explain it correctly. That `OrderBy` is meant to show what is the resulting order determined by the standard string comparison. That's why I asked if that is the order that an IComparable implementation should return. The interface implementation is quite simple here, maybe the OP finds difficult to implement some specific order (maybe some numeric non-natural :).

Comment: Yes, I know you have a `ToString()` method. Still, you don't have a Property. Also, that method, if implemented like that, is quite useless. You should use it to return a complex value. If you return the value of an interrnal field directly, that's the job of a public property.

Comment: You need to use properties.  Only properties support data-binding, i.e. you can't set the `ValueMember` and then use `SelectedValue` in a `ComboBox` with the class you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably shouldn't do this but I will anyway.  Here's a solution using `IComparable(Of T)`:

```
Public Class ListControlItem
    Implements IComparable, IComparable(Of ListControlItem)

    Public Property Value As String
    Public Property Text As String

    Public Sub New(value As String, text As String)
        Me.Value = value
        Me.Text = text
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Text
    End Function

    Public Function CompareTo(obj As Object) As Integer Implements IComparable.CompareTo
        Return CompareTo(DirectCast(obj, ListControlItem))
    End Function

    Public Function CompareTo(other As ListControlItem) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of ListControlItem).CompareTo
        Return Text.CompareTo(other.Text)
    End Function

End Class
```

and then simply sort like this:

```
myListControlItemList.Sort()
```

Here's a solution using `IComparer(Of T)`:

```
Public Class ListControlItem

    Public Property Value As String
    Public Property Text As String

    Public Sub New(value As String, text As String)
        Me.Value = value
        Me.Text = text
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Text
    End Function

End Class

Public Class ListControlItemComparer
    Implements IComparer, IComparer(Of ListControlItem)

    Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare
        Return Compare(DirectCast(x, ListControlItem), DirectCast(y, ListControlItem))
    End Function

    Public Function Compare(x As ListControlItem, y As ListControlItem) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of ListControlItem).Compare
        Return x.Text.CompareTo(y.Text)
    End Function

End Class
```

and then sort like this:

```
myListControlItemList.Sort(New ListControlItemComparer)
```

Here's a solution using the `Comparison(Of T)` delegate, which does an ad hoc sort without any other classes or interfaces:

```
myListControlItemList.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Text.CompareTo(y.Text))
```

Notice that, in all three cases, the actual comparison is pretty much exactly the same.

By the way, also note that it is considered good practice to implement both the non-generic and generic versions of an interface when both exist.  AS I have demonstrated here, the non-generic implementation can simply perform a cast and pass the work off to the generic implementation.

As I think I mention in my blog posts, the `IComparable` interface is a good option when there is an obvious way that items should be compared in all or most cases.  Once the type being compared implements its own comparison, no one has to do any extra work to use it.  The `IComparer` interface is a good option if there are multiple ways the items could be compared and/or the comparison is complex and comparisons will be required in multiple places.  It allows you to put all the comparison logic in one place and then use it in multiple places with little extra code.  The `Comparison` delegate is good for ad hoc sorting because you put the logic right where you need to use it.

As an aside, I have used properties in these examples and you should do the same.  Properties should almost always be used for exposing data publicly and they are also required for use in data-binding.  In this case, it might even be appropriate to use `ReadOnly` properties, if the intention is that the data not be changed once the objects are created.

As a bonus, here's an example of a complex comparison.  I'll do it by extending the third example above for simplicity but it can be done in any of the three cases because, as I said, the actual comparison is done in pretty much exactly the same way in all three cases.

```
myListControlItemList.Sort(Function(x, y)
                               'Sort by Text by default.
                               Dim result = x.Text.CompareTo(y.Text)

                               If result = 0 Then
                                   'Sort by Value if Text is equal.
                                   result = x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value)
                               End If

                               Return result
                           End Function)
```

Comment: Good explanation. Quite extended for something you *shouldn't have done* :) I'ld move that last comment of yours into the answer. On top of it, IMO.

Comment: @Jimi, I've added a note re properties but not quite so prominently, given that it is not central to the process of sorting, which is the point of the original question.  It is relevant in the context the class is being used in though.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Awesome. Now I understand it anyway sir. Thank you. :) God Bless